# is the dust or dirt in USB bad to USB port?

Tags: usb, cleaning

I've got a new laptop that I like, but my USB stick has quite some dirt that is sticky and unable to clean, and some dirt which looks like an oxidization or even corrosion. Plugging it into the new laptop USB port, could it be any problems to the laptop

Comment: Depends really on the extent and location of the damage. Corrosion around the pins could be rather bad, and could cause short circuiting and malfunction of the device. A bit of dirt is not likely to be as bad, as dirt is less likely to be conductive. Can you post clear photos taken close up in good lighting?

Comment: If you don't already have one, get an **external (add-on) hub** -- in my part of the world, they are about USD4 in nearly every office or electronics store, supermarket, pharmacy, and gas station, and I wouldn't be surprised to see them at a burger joint -- and use that. If you do damage it, it's much easier and cheaper to replace than repairing your laptop is.

Comment: "could it be any problems to the laptop"? Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Try zippo to clean it. The problem that sticky dirt can cause usb reader port at your laptop unread because the dirt act like insulation. The corrosion not hardly damage your laptop when intact but the damage only on usb stick itself. Try cleaning with alcohol or zippo for electronic cleaning.

Answer (score 0):

A little dust shouldn't do any harm, its when you get meatal dust or something like that that it can get bad. Just clean the stick with IPA or similar and you will be fine.

Answer (score -1):

Dirt can cause short circuit between the plates of the usb stick and this is not good . Have you tried WD40 it helps remove dirt, grime, grease and corrosion on metals that normally won't come out.

Comment: If you mean WD-40® Specialist® Fast Drying Electrical Contact Cleaner Spray you should probably specify that. Using normal WD-40 on an USB port is a very very bad idea.